# "groupby" method throwing "Length of values does not match length of index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have hourly data from 2013-2019 that measures wind speed from a weather station every hour.  I'd like to group that by year and graph each year (see code) below.  The only thing is that the 2013 starts in September and 2016 was a leap year, so I think the reason I'm getting the error is the unevenness of the number of data points per year?  Would I be right on this?  How might I work around it?

```
# create stacked lined plot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Grouper
from matplotlib import pyplot

series = read_csv('2013-2019 MR Wind.csv', header=0, index_col=0,
                  parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
groups = series.groupby(Grouper(freq='A'))
years = DataFrame()
for name, group in groups:
    years[name.year] = group.values  #code fails here
years.plot(subplots=True, legend=False)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: `from pandas import Series` and `years[name.year] = Series(group.values)`

Comment: Thanks, that cleared the error and printed the graphs. But 2013 which only has data from September appears like it it has data for the entire year.  And the x-axis is now from 1 to 3000 rather than the regular datetime stamp.  Thoughts?